# How to read json with the given structure on scala play?

Tags: json, scala

I have a json list structure like this, how can we read this structure and convert in a list in scala, play framwork.

```
{
"0":{
    "name":"Foo",
    "age":10
  },
"12":{
    "name":"Bar",
     "age":10
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

If, there were json structure like below, I could have done it easily, but since I am not that versed in parsing Json and actually new to scala too, I couldn't understand how to work with Json strucutures that have key as "0","12" like in the first example. I had been using Jerkson wrapper for Jackson for generating/parsing json/case-class.

```
{
{"name":"Foo","age":10},
{"name":"Bar",age:11}
}
```

Update:

I actually succeeded in parsing the json structure, in addition to Ryans answer,

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Doodad(name: String, age: Int)

object Doodad {
  implicit val fmt = Json.format[Doodad]

def parserFuntion = {
var myJsValue: JsValue = Json.parse(jsonString)// added line in the ans
    var requiredMap = myJsValue.validate[Map[String, Doodad]]
}
    }
```

But now I have a new questions, the json structure I working with seems to be a bit irregular for eg:

```
{
"0":{
    "name":"Foo",
    "age":10
  },
"12":{
    "name":"Bar",
    "age":10
  },
"13":{
    "name":"Foobar"
    "age":20,
    "meta":{
             "desc":"Irregular Json",
             "img":"Some Link"
           }
  },
      .
      .
      .
    }
```

Chances are some of the json list elements might have that extra "meta" key->value pair, and some might not. So, how can we deal with such situations. Any ideas??

Comment: A case class may be, I need to read the data and convert it to a list. May be a `Seq[Person]`

Comment: What should happen if there are missing or duplicate numbers representing keys in the JSON?

Comment: Lets just assume, the index keys will be there and unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
case class Doodad(name: String, age: Int)

object Doodad {
  implicit val fmt = Json.format[Doodad]
}

myJsValue.validate[Map[String, Doodad]] // JsResult[Map[String, Doodad]]
```

Comment: Hey @ryan, could you elaborate a bit in its usage??

Comment: Everything you need to know is in the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson

Comment: I have already checked at the documentation link, and like I have pointed in the question, I can properly carry out parsing for normal json like in the example, I am only having problem with the first json structure, so can't you just provide a brief explanation of your answer??